# Type definition - cannot use basic type as custom type even though basic type is source of custom type

Tags: go, types

In the below code, we are using [type definition](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_definitions) syntax in Line 5,6,7:

```
package math

// Constructors and Selectors

type RationalNumber []int                      // Line 5
type Numerator int
type Denominator int

// Constructor - Construct a rational number x that represents n/d
func NewRationalNumber(n int, d int) RationalNumber {
    g := gcd(n, d) 
    return []int{n / g, d / g}             // Line 12
}

//Selector
func numer(x RationalNumber) Numerator {
    return x[0]                           // Line 17
}

//Selector
func denom(x RationalNumber) Denominator {
    return x[1]
}
```

---

`return []int{n / g, d / g}` does not give error,

where as,

`return x[0]` & `return x[1]` give error:

```
math/numbers.go:17:10: cannot use x[0] (type int) as type Numerator in return argument
math/numbers.go:22:10: cannot use x[1] (type int) as type Denominator in return argument
```

---

For given 3 type definitions in Line 5,6,7, I understand the reason behind error on Line 17, but,

1. Why Line 12 does not give similar error?
2. How to resolve this error? without changing the signature of functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question bothered me as well, so here is answer that i came up with.

Take your function as an example:

```
func NewRationalNumber(n int, d int) RationalNumber {
    g := gcd(n, d) 
    return []int{n / g, d / g}
}
```

According to function signature, it should return `RationalNumber` type, but in fact it returns `int` slice. Reason why it works is that type `[]int` is assignable to type `RationalNumber`. Specifically it satisfies second condition, [mentioned in language spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability):

> x's type V and T have identical underlying types and at least one of V or T is not a defined type.

This condition is satisfied, because in that case, we have only one defined type(`RationalNumber`) and another one is composite type(`[]int`).

So, why do we get error when we define following function?:

```
func numer(x RationalNumber) Numerator {
    return x[0]
}
```

Type `Numerator` has `int` as underlying type and we return `int`, which is predeclared type, so it should work, right? No) Thing is, although `int` is predeclared, it's still defined type. As it's stated in [language spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Numeric_types):

> To avoid portability issues all numeric types are defined types

In fact, all [predeclared types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Predeclared_identifiers), except `error`, are defined types.

Comment: So, how do I make one of the type unnamed(not defined)? in case of `numer()` function...to make things work

Answer (score 2):

The defined type `RationalNumber` was created from a slice with elements of type **`int`**, therefore subscription on an instance of the defined type gives an `int`, not any of the newly defined types created from `int`.

The compiler does not complain about line 12 since the syntax is the **slice literal** appropriate for creating the defined type (hint: elements of new slice type are `int`).

Comment: OK, agreed. but as mentioned in your answer, on same lines.... `return []int{n / g, d / g}` is returning `[]int` type but not `RationalNumber` type. Why compiler does not complain on this? Why the compiler is not expecting the signature to be `func NewRationalNumber(n int, d int) []int {}`?

Comment: `RationalNumber` is a slice and the appropriate slice literal for creating an instance is `[]int{}`.

Comment: On same lines..... I can also say, `Numerator` is an `int`, but for compiler, `Numerator` and `int` are two distint types. Similarly, `RationalNumber` & `[]int` are also two distinct types. So, For `return []int{1,2}` syntax, compile should expect return type to be `[]int` but not `RationalNumber`. Isn't it?

Comment: They are distinct types. But the elements of `RationalNumber` are `int` nonetheless. The slice literal syntax is syntactic sugar.

Comment: Did you mean.... *Two slice types are identical if they have identical element types*, as mentioned [here](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_identity)?

Comment: `type Numerator = int` is resolving the error. How `type Numerator  int` different from `type Numerator = int`?

Comment: Re 1: Yes, the underlying type for `RationalNumber` is `[]int` so assignability works both ways since at least one of them is not a defined type: `var r RationalNumber = []int{}` and `var s []int = RationalNumber{}` both work.

Comment: Re 2: `type Numerator = int` is an **alias** and does not define a new type.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning a type different from what was specified in the function definitions.

Take `numer(x RationalNumber) Numerator` for example

`numer(x RationalNumber) Numerator` accepts a variable of type `RationalNumber` and is expected to return a variable of type `Numerator`.
The problem is that you are returning a type `int` (as RationalNumber is a **slice** of **int**s) but a type `Numerator` is expected.

You can refactor your code to cast the `int` returned by `RationalNumber` to the appropriate types.

```golang
type RationalNumber []int                    
type Numerator int
type Denominator int

func NewRationalNumber(n int, d int) RationalNumber {
    g := gcd(n, d) 
    return []int{n / g, d / g}  
}

func numer(x RationalNumber) Numerator {
    return Numerator(x[0])                     
}

func denom(x RationalNumber) Denominator {
    return Denominator(x[1])
}
```

> I know that, my question is why there is no necessity to do RationalNumber([]int{n / g, d / g})?

You do not need to do so because []int{n/g, d/g} is already a slice of ints.

> type Numerator = int syntax is resolving the error. Am not sure, how type Numerator = int different from type Numerator  int? No need to Numerator(x[0])

`type Numerator = int` is a type alias for `int`. This does not create a new type that is distinct from `int`.

Whereas `type Numerator int` creates a new custom type called `Numerator` which has a source type of `int`. `Numerator` can be cast to `int` but it is distinct from `int`

You can refer to [Type definitions vs Type Alias](https://go101.org/article/type-system-overview.html) for more explanations

Comment: I know that, my question is... why there is no necessity to do `RationalNumber([]int{n / g, d / g})`?

Comment: @overexchange you do not need to do so because `[]int{n/g, d/g}` is already a slice of ints.

Comment: `type Numerator = int` syntax is resolving the error. Am not sure, how `type Numerator = int` different from `type Numerator  int`? No need to `Numerator(x[0])`

Comment: @overexchange that is because `type Numerator = int` is a `type` alias for `int`. Whereas `type Numerator int` creates a new custom type called `Numerator` which has a source type of `int`. `Numerator` can be cast to `int` but is distinct from `int`